# Add Vue 3 to CMS generated HTML

Tags: vue.js

i got a site with a cms here, which generates html the common way. Now i try to add Vue 3. CSS and JS is created by webpack.

The CMS generates a source like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/dist/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
      <MyComponent />
      <div>Awesome Copyright</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to mount vue 3 to #app, but keep the source as structure/content for the page and use vue 3 inside? Like setting {{name}} to a value from vue and MyComponent from a vue file? And all JS is compiled by webpack?

I did not figure out how to solve this. Something like SSR seems not to be a practicable solution and switching to a headless constellation with the cms as api is not either.

Comment: I changed the text to clarify that all JS should be done by webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading and understanding the documentation, i answer myself.

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#with-a-bundler
See section "In-browser template compilation".

Step 1: Alias vue within webpack

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js"
    }
  }
```

Step 2: Run Vue ;-)

```
createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'John Doe'
    }
  },
}).mount('#app')
```

The definition of template is not necessary. It takes the content from #app.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this

```
createApp({
  data() { return {} },
  template: document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML
}).mount('#app')
```

Comment: Good idea. But it ignores any value handed over via template - your suggestion or a string. Front end stays empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How are you trying to pass the value in? I made a Codepen showing a working example of what I suggested: https://codepen.io/nVitius/pen/bGBBMQE

Comment: Yes, this is working. I was able to reproduce it. But unfortunately not with webpack, only when vue is linked from external, like unpkg.